# How to correctly use pipe to transfer data from child process to parent process?

Tags: c++, fork, execvp

I'm trying to create a function that returns true if execvp is successful and false if it is not. Initially, I didn't use a pipe and the problem was that whenever execvp failed, I get 2 returns, one false and one true (from the parent). Now that I'm piping, I'm never getting a false returned when execvp fails.

I know there are a lot related questions and answers on this topic, but I can't seem to narrow down where my particular error is. What I want is for my variables return_type_child, return_type_parent, and this->return_type to all contain the same value. I expected that in the child process, execvp would fail so the next lines would execute. As a result, I thought that the 3 variables mentioned would all be false, but instead when I print out the value in this->return_type, 1 is displayed.

```
bool Command::execute() {
    this->fork_helper();
    return return_type;
}

void Command::fork_helper() {
    bool return_type_child = true;
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    pid_t child;
    char *const argv[] = {"zf","-la", nullptr};
    child = fork();
    if (child > 0) {
        wait(NULL);
        close(0);
        close(fd[1]);
        dup(fd[0]);
        bool return_type_parent = read(fd[0], &return_type_child, sizeof(return_
        this->return_type = return_type_parent;
    }
    else if (child == 0) {
        close(fd[0]);
        close(1);
        dup(fd[1]);
        execvp(argv[0], argv);
        this->return_type = false;
        return_type_child = false;
        write(1,&return_type_child,sizeof(return_type_child));
    }
    return;
}
```

I've also tried putting a cout statement after execvp(argv[0], argv), which never ran. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You leak `fd[0]` in the parent. Also, if `execvp` succeeds, who or what writes the return information to the parent?

Comment: you will never ever run a piece of code you wrote after execvp.
The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image

Comment: Okay I think I get it. do you have any other recommendations for doing this? the main thing i need is to return a bool based on whether execvp fails or succeeds

Comment: fork returns the pid of the child processes. you can wait for and then query in the parent if child has exited and what its return value was.
https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait

Answer (score 0):

From the code, it seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (edit: moved this section to the front due to a comment that confirms this). If the goal is to get the exit status of the child, then for that there is the value that [`wait` returns](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/wait.html), and no pipes are required:

```
int stat;
wait(&stat);
```

Read the manual of `wait` to figure out how to read it. The value of `stat` can be tested as follows:

- WEXITSTATUS(stat) - If WIFEXITED(stat) != 0, then this are the lower 8 bits of child's call to `exit(N)` or the return value from `main`. It might work correctly without checking WIFEXITED, but the standard does not specify that.
- WTERMSIG(stat) - If WIFSIGNALED(stat) != 0, then this is the signal number that caused the process to exit (e.g. 11 is segmentation fault). It might work correctly without checking WIFSIGNALED, but the standard does not specify that.

There are several errors in the code. See the added comments:

```
void Command::fork_helper() {
    // File descriptors here: 0=stdin, 1=stdout, 2=stderr 
    //(and 3..N opened in the program, could also be none).
    bool return_type_child = true;
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    // File descriptors here: 0=stdin, 1=stdout, 2=stderr 
    //(and 3..N opened in the program, could also be none).
    // N+1=fd[0] data exhaust of the pipe
    // N+2=fd[1] data intake of the pipe
    pid_t child;
    char *const argv[] = {"zf","-la", nullptr};
    child = fork();
    if (child > 0) {
        // This code is executed in the parent.
        wait(NULL); // wait for the child to complete.
```

This `wait` is a potential deadlock: if the child [writes enough data to the pipe (usually in the kilobytes)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer), the write blocks and waits for the parent to read the pipe. The parent wait(NULL) waits for the child to complete, which which waits for the parent to read the pipe. This is likely not effecting the code in question, but it is problematic.

```
        close(0);
        close(fd[1]);
        dup(fd[0]);
        // File descriptors here: 0=new stdin=data exhaust of the pipe
        // 1=stdout, 2=stderr 
        // (and 3..N opened in the program, could also be none).
        // N+1=fd[0] data exhaust of the pipe (stdin is now a duplicate)
```

This is problematic since:

1. the code just lost the original stdin.
2. The pipe is never closed. You should close fd[0] explicitly, don't close(0), 
   and don't duplicate fd[0].
3. It is good idea to avoid having duplicate descriptors, except for having stderr duplicate stdout.

.

```
        bool return_type_parent = read(fd[0], &return_type_child, sizeof(return_
        this->return_type = return_type_parent;

    }
    else if (child == 0) {
        // this code runs in the child.
        close(fd[0]);
        close(1);
        dup(fd[1]);
        // File descriptors here: 0=stdin, 1=new stdout=pipe intake, 2=stderr 
        //(and 3..N opened in the program, could also be none).
        // N+2=fd[1] pipe intake (new stdout is a duplicate)
```

This is problematic, since there are two duplicate data intakes to the pipe. In this case it is not critical since they are both closed automatically when the process ends, but it is a bad practice. It is a bad practice, since only closing all the pipe intakes signals END-OF-FILE to the exhaust. Closing one intake but not the other, does not signal END-OF-FILE. Again, in your case it is not causing trouble since the child's exit closes all the intakes.

```
        execvp(argv[0], argv);
```

The code below the above line is never reached, unless `execvp` itself failed. The `execvp` fails only when the file does not exist, or the caller has no permission to execute it. If the executable starts to execute and fails later (possibly even if it fails to read a shared library), then still `execvp` itself succeeds and never returns. This is because `execvp` replaces the executable, and the following code is no longer in memory when `execvp` starts to run the other program.

```
        this->return_type = false;
        return_type_child = false;
        write(1,&return_type_child,sizeof(return_type_child));
    }
    return;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I took out the pipe and am just trying to work with waitpid. Now, my issue is that I'm always getting a return true (`waitpid(child, &status, 0)` and then checking if `WIFEXITED(status)` is nonzero. I'm guessing that's where the problem is.

Comment: @SarahAllec waitpid does not return a boolean. In your case it only returns the process id of the child. The status can be extracted only from the `status` variable